# Retrieving form session without saving

Tags: jsf, session

I am trying to retrieve data from the session for my program. My problem is that I want to check if something already exists or has just been created. Therefore I want to check the session like this:

```
//status if party exists or not

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();  
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);  

String i = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("create");

//in case of the party doesn't exists
if (i.equals(null)) {
    httpSession.setAttribute("create", "1"); //I never used a set before for this value
    homeBean.getParty().setOrgKey(generateKey("org"));
    homeBean.getParty().setGastKey(generateKey("gast"));
    insertParty();          
}
else {
    updateParty();
}
```

I am always having a `NullPointerException`. Is there a possibillity to resolve this?

Comment: what do you mean ? and change `i == null` for comparison with `null`

Comment: @Jigar srr didnt see it

Comment: null == NULL <- well i should start writing it diffrent right?

Comment: that won't cause NPE, something else is `null` as well

Comment: alright finnaly it worked i dont know how i dont know why.... but it worked <3

Comment: what changed ? if you changed `equals()` to == then `i` was `null`

Answer (score 1):

alright here is the sollution.

this code works somehow. I don't know why but it works and this is everything what I wanted :D

```
public void createParty() {
    // status ob die party existiert wird aus der session geholt
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);

    if (httpSession.getAttribute("create") == null) {
        httpSession.setAttribute("create", 1);
        homeBean.getParty().setOrgKey(generateKey("org"));
        homeBean.getParty().setGastKey(generateKey("gast"));
        insertParty();
    } else {
        int i = (Integer) httpSession.getAttribute("create");
        if (i == 1) {
            updateParty();
        }
    }
}
```

it was like someone said I should check the httpSession if it's null or not

TL;DR

OP changed `equals()` to `==`, so `i` was `null`

you are a troll right? :D nearly like every single software developper

alright but now it looks like this

```
//this method has to be called before createParty()
    public String cvParty() {
        party = new Party();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
        httpSession.setAttribute("create", 0);
        return "partyDetail?faces-redirect=true&i=2";
    }
```

---

```
public void createParty() {
    // status ob die party existiert wird aus der session geholt
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);

    if ((Integer) httpSession.getAttribute("create") == 1) {
        updateParty();
    }
    else {
        httpSession.setAttribute("create", 1);
        homeBean.getParty().setOrgKey(generateKey("org"));
        homeBean.getParty().setGastKey(generateKey("gast"));
        insertParty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one side note : Exposing functionality directly from the underlying `javax.servlet` API does not dictates a good practice. Well-coded beans typically contain zero dependencies from the `javax.servlet` API. In this case, you could instead obtain a session map from the JSF context such as `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()` and then get/set session attributes as your need using its `Map#get(key);` and `Map#put(key, value);` methods respectively. To be continued.

Comment: In this conditional check, `if ((Integer) httpSession.getAttribute("create") == 1)`, If you change the constant value `1` to another `Integer` object and if you exceed a range between `-128` and `+127` (inclusive), the comparison will fail. Compare them using the `equals()` method instead. In this conditional test in your question `if (i.equals(null))`, object equals `null` is never true hereby you always need a comparison of an object with `null` using `==`.